# Saved classes to the icon after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
   <div class="places-item">
      <div class="places-item-img"></div>
      <div class="places-item-header">
         <h2>Machu Picchu, Peru</h2>
         <div class="places-item-header-add"><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='512' height='512' viewBox='0 0 512 512'><path d='M352,48H160a48,48,0,0,0-48,48V464L256,336,400,464V96A48,48,0,0,0,352,48Z' style='fill:transparent;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:32px'/></svg></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="places-item">
      <div class="places-item-img"></div>
      <div class="places-item-header">
         <h2>Ciucaș Peak, Romania</h2>
         <div class="places-item-header-add"><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='512' height='512' viewBox='0 0 512 512'><path d='M352,48H160a48,48,0,0,0-48,48V464L256,336,400,464V96A48,48,0,0,0,352,48Z' style='fill:transparent;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:32px'/></svg></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

```
.places-item {
    width: 100%;
}
.places-item-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
.places-item-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
.places-item-header h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 38px);
}
.places-item-header-add {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.places-item-header-add svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.places-item-header-add.added svg path {
    fill: #000 !important;
}
```

```
var addBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.places-item-header-add');

for(i=0;i<addBtn.length;++i)addBtn[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
  this.classList.toggle('added');
});
```

When you click on the icon, it becomes black. What can I do to make the icon that was clicked (there may be several of them) black after refreshing the page? I was planning to do this at localStorage.

Comment: yes use local storage and instead of storing the index we can store some id to specify which place item was active like ```{ peru: true, romania: true }```

Comment: You could help me more accurately? Because I'm a beginner and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Read on local storage and try doing it yourself, if you get stuck do ask. But don't ask people to do the whole thing for you, that's not how StackOverflow works. https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be specific to your elements, add ids so that we can specify which item was active.
example.

add id to your item header.
`<div id='peru' class="places-item-header-add">`

and when the window is loaded check the value in the localstorage and update the item class.

```
var addBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.places-item-header-add');
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selected_items')) || {};

for (i = 0; i < addBtn.length; ++i) {
  if (items[addBtn[i].id]) {
    addBtn[i].classList.add('added');
  }
  addBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('added');
    if (this.classList.contains('added')) {
      items[this.id] = true;
    } else {
      items[this.id] = false;
    }
    localStorage.setItem('selected_items', JSON.stringify(items));
  })
}
```

Check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/uwqevc65/